# How can I convert a string with the name of a class into a class that a Generic will accept?

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have the following code:

```
var something = UnityContainer.Resolve<IService<Package>>();
```

This works good as Package is the name of a class which I define and which is set up and mapped by Unity. However in my application my class is coming into the method as a **string parameter**. Something like this:

```
public void Update(string className) {

var something = UnityContainer.Resolve<IService<Package>>();
```

Is there a way that I can take the className string and use it in the above generic just like a class?

Comment: how is class name exactly used? or how do you expect it to be used?

Comment: Did my or any other answer help you mark them as correct. If you have a own solution please add it here.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used the UnityContainer, but I think you can resolve a component passing a type as a parameter. You can do something like this:

```
Type packageType = Type.GetType(className);
Type openGenericType = typeof(IService<>);
Type myClosedType = openGenericType.MakeGenericType(packageType);
var something = UnityContainer.Resolve(myClosedType);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an instanced method on the Type class called "MakeGenericType", with that, you can pass in the type(s) you want to use for the generic parameters like below:

```
    public void Update(string className)
    {
        var targetType = Type.GetType(className);
        var serviceType = typeof(IService<>);
        var genericParam = serviceType.MakeGenericType(targetType);
        var unityType = typeof(UnityContainer);
        var resolve = unityType.GetMethod("Resolve");
        var targetMethod = resolve.MakeGenericMethod(genericParam);
        var something = targetMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { genericParam });
        //...
```

Comment: This is giving me the following compile time error error: Error 2 No overload for method 'Resolve' takes 1 arguments

Comment: Sorry, I've never used Unity before. I was just taking a swing at it. My answer has been updated to call the generic method though.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var t = asm.GetType("ConsoleApplication1.Test");
```

where ConsoleApplication1 is the assmebly name the Test is the class name

Answer (score 0):

The *Resolve* methods are mostly extension methods defined by the [UnityContainerExtensions class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.unitycontainerextension%28PandP.20%29.aspx).
The only overload of *Resolve* that is an instance method of *UnityContainer* is [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660794%28PandP.20%29.aspx).